# Don't track commits from a certain Github repo in developer overview page on Github

Tags: git, github

I work on an open-source project and so I have a lot of commits from that in my Github history when on the Github user page. However I also have a clone of that repo in another repository where I store the files for the repo that I have live on the internet. This works well as a flow for working separately on the OS project and also my version of the software that is in a Private repo, the issue is that I get my commit history double counted on my developer overview page. I get a lot out of seeing my Github history so to see the commits from this project doubled throws the data off and I'm wondering if there's a way around this. Can I tell Github to not track the commits from that specific repo? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you [don't push to the default branch](https://help.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile) of the repo then the commits won't show up in your commit graph.